# Passing a String/Object value to another ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, swift3, uistoryboard

I am opening another ViewController using this:

```
let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name:"Main", bundle:nil)
let homeViewController: UIViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "IssueViewController")
self.present(homeViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Along with this, I need to pass a Person object and a String value to the 2nd ViewController.

```
struct Person {
  var Name: String
  var Details: String
}
```

What changes do I need to do to attach a Person object to my existing code?

**EDIT: This is the 2nd ViewController**

I am trying to retrieve the values from this view

```
class IssueViewController: UIViewController {

    var person: Person = Person();

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

}
```

Comment: Issue view controller has to have propery Person and all what you need is set homeViewController.person to your object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

//changes in first controller

```
let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name:"Main",bundle:Bundle.main)
let homeViewController: IssueViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "IssueViewController") as! IssueViewController
homeViewController.person = Person(Name:"ABC",Details:"XYZ")
homeViewController.bindWithData(yourStringObject)
self.present(homeViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

//changes in second view controller

```
class IssueViewController: UIViewController {

var person: Person = Person(Name:"",Details:"");

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    print(person.Name)
    print(person.Details)
}
func bindWithData(yourStringObject:String){
//your code here.
}
}
```

Comment: I get this error when I set the person to the homeViewController: `Value of type 'UIViewController' has no member 'person'`

Comment: have you defined struct Person there ?

Comment: hey sorry there was an issue with the code i have fixed it in the edit please review.

Comment: Thanks yeah the error is gone. But where do I receive the person object in the second VC? Inside the viewDidLoad? Can you show that with a `print()` code line

Comment: I get a nil value in the 2nd VC's print statement. Your code is okay right?